# DropShadowEffect applied multiple times on WPF custom control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, custom-controls

I'm writing a WPF custom control that displays an overlay for loading processes. This custom control derives from [ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) and reuses it's [Effect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.effect.aspx) dependency property to display a drop shadow.

However the drop shadow is unexpectely and unwantedly displayed two times. I've tried to find any logic to this, but do not know how to solve this. Anyone got a clue how to remove the shadow on the outer border?

[image: Shadow displayed on outer border and inner border.]

**LoadingOverlay.cs**

```
public class LoadingOverlay : ContentControl
{
    static LoadingOverlay()
    {
        Type currentType = typeof(LoadingOverlay);
        FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            currentType,
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(currentType));
    }
}
```

**Themes\Generic.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="local:LoadingOverlay">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#BBFFFFFF" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF266ECC" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:LoadingOverlay">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Effect="{x:Null}">
                    <Border Effect="{TemplateBinding Effect}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FFFFFFFF" BorderBrush="#FF266ECC" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Setting Effect at LoadingOverlay level, try setting Effect at inner Border level. Then you won't have to set the upper Border Effect to {x:null} as well. See below:

```
<Style TargetType="local:LoadingOverlay">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#BBFFFFFF" />
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF266ECC" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:LoadingOverlay">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FFFFFFFF" BorderBrush="#FF266ECC" BorderThickness="1">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```